# PHP сбрасывается число в кэше

Tags: php

Сделал элементарный подсчёт просмотров страниц:

```
$cache = json_decode(fgets(fopen('/home/user/site.com/assets/cache.tmp', 'r')), true);

//добавляем к количеству счетчика +1
$cache['counter'][$_POST['type']] = strval($count = $cache['counter'][$_POST['type']] +1); 

fwrite(fopen('/home/user/site.com/assets/cache.tmp', 'w'), json_encode($cache));
```

Но дело в том что число раз в день не по понятным мне причинам сбрасывается. Изначально было 4700000 (взято из прошлых данных). Сегодня в обед захожу и вижу такое содержимое файла:

```
{"counter"
:{
"ch":"41"}
}
```

А должно быть  ch: ~4702930

Укажите пожалуйста в чем это может быть проблема? Из-за большого числа? - Так вроде же перевёл в strval.

Comment: Тут дело не в strval, претензий может быть много, более надежно в вашем случае выглядит такой код: `$cache = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache.txt'), true);
$cache['counter'][$_POST['type']] = $cache['counter'][$_POST['type']] + 1;
file_put_contents('cache.txt', json_encode($cache));`

Comment: @Manitikyl изначально так и пробовал, потом подумал что число int сильно большое (4.7 миллиона) и присвоил строковое значение.

Comment: Ды как-бы у `int` большие допуски) Но я думаю проблемы со считыванием файла (одновременно происходит и запись и считка), поэтому используйте либо бд и один запрос, либо тот пример что я предложил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, при чтении файла происходят ошибки, которые вы не проверяете. В результате переменная `$cache` у вас получается пустой.

Попробуйте такой код

```
function inc_counter($file_name, $type) {
  $data = file_get_contents($file_name);
  if ($data === false)
    return false;
  $json = json_decode($data, true);
  if ($json === null)
    return false;
  $json['counter'][$type]++;
  $data = json_encode($json);
  if ($data === false)
    return false;
  return file_put_contents($file_name, $data, LOCK_EX) !== false;
}

inc_counter('/home/user/site.com/assets/cache.tmp', $_POST['type']);
```

А еще лучше использовать БД, где все блокировки уже реализованы

Comment: Спасибо но я любитель лаконичности по этому сделал так:  $cache['counter'][$_POST['type']] = ($count = $cache['counter'][$_POST['type']] + 1) > 0 ? $count : null;

Comment: Ваша "лаконичность" уже привела к нерабочему коду

Comment: К багу в коде привело отсутствие проверок.